Prevent keyboard dismiss when tapping outside
In Flutter web, the default behavior of a Text Field is that when tapping or interacting with any widget outside of it, the keyboard dismisses.
I was wondering how to disable this kind of behavior.

Here is the code of the example shown in the GIF:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            TextField(
              controller: TextEditingController(text: ''),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thank you.

Maybe you can subclass FocusNode and use this? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/consumeKeyboardToken.html
I can't test it right now.

You can achieve this using PopScope, Here's the result:

Here's the code:
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test Pop Scope'),),
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: 'press Here'
        )
      )),
    );


This does not work for me... did you test it on web using a mobile device? I think that the issue that I am experiencing is only on web with a mobile device.

@אוריorihpt , it's working on mobile!. if you are working with web, focus node will deal with that

Thank you for you assistance @A-E , but I'm experiencing this issue in mobile on web specifically. I tried to run your code on web and go to the local website from an iOS simulator, but unfortunately I am still experiencing the same issue.
